# Haystack index on attribute inherited by model

Tags: python, django, django-models, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a problem filtering on indexes in Haystack (Elasticsearch) when model_attr refers to an inherited attribute.

For instance, with the code:

django models.py

```
Parent(models.Model):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Child(Parent):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

search_index.py

```
class ChildIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    is_active = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='is_active')

    def get_model(self):
        return Child

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

and the following instances

```
Child.objects.create(title='matches keyword', is_active=True)
Child.objects.create(title='also matches keyword but not active', is_active=False)
```

a search with "keyword" and SearchQuerySet().models(Resource).filter(is_active=True) will return both instances, when only the first is expected...
I have not much eperience with Haystack but it seems to me that it does not even consider the index. 
E.g. SearchQuerySet().models(Resource).filter(is_active='something that is not even a Boolean') will also return both result. I have refreshed my indexes with rebuild_index.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had in fact nothing to do with inheritance, but with the way querysets are filtered, as Aamir suggested.
The solution is SearchQuerySet().models(Resource).filter(is_active=1)

Answer (score 0):

In Haystack you filter on boolean field as:

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Resource).filter(is_active='true') # or 'false'
```

Comment: Thank you Aamir. The problem remains the same, haystack seems not to filter